# Freeze and unfreeze certain layers in TFDistilBertModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to implement either TFBertModel or TFDistilBertModel in my neural network model (there are other layers such as dense and batch norm). My understanding is that there are hidden layer in either of the BERT model and I want to unfreeze the last two layers for the purpose of fine tuning.

However, after I ran the following code:

```
model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased', config=config)
print(len(model.layers))
```

it shows that there is only one layer, and I think it's referring to TFDistilBertModel as a whole. Is there a way for me to unfreeze and freeze some of the hidden layers in order to fine tune the model?

Comment: Good question on a feature that's mostly under-documented =)

Answer (score 2):

First, we need to access the layers/params with its name so that we know what we want to freeze/unfreeze:

```
from transformers import AutoModel

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

for m in model.modules():
  for name, params in m.named_parameters():
    print(name, params.requires_grad)
```

[out]:

```
embeddings.word_embeddings.weight True
embeddings.position_embeddings.weight True
embeddings.LayerNorm.weight True
embeddings.LayerNorm.bias True
transformer.layer.0.attention.q_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.0.attention.q_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.0.attention.k_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.0.attention.k_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.0.attention.v_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.0.attention.v_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.0.attention.out_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.0.attention.out_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.0.sa_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.0.sa_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin1.weight True
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin1.bias True
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin2.weight True
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin2.bias True
transformer.layer.0.output_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.0.output_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.1.attention.q_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.1.attention.q_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.1.attention.k_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.1.attention.k_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.1.attention.v_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.1.attention.v_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.1.attention.out_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.1.attention.out_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.1.sa_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.1.sa_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.1.ffn.lin1.weight True
transformer.layer.1.ffn.lin1.bias True
transformer.layer.1.ffn.lin2.weight True
transformer.layer.1.ffn.lin2.bias True
transformer.layer.1.output_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.1.output_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.2.attention.q_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.2.attention.q_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.2.attention.k_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.2.attention.k_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.2.attention.v_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.2.attention.v_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.2.attention.out_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.2.attention.out_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.2.sa_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.2.sa_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.2.ffn.lin1.weight True
transformer.layer.2.ffn.lin1.bias True
transformer.layer.2.ffn.lin2.weight True
transformer.layer.2.ffn.lin2.bias True
transformer.layer.2.output_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.2.output_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.3.attention.q_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.3.attention.q_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.3.attention.k_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.3.attention.k_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.3.attention.v_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.3.attention.v_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.3.attention.out_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.3.attention.out_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.3.sa_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.3.sa_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.3.ffn.lin1.weight True
transformer.layer.3.ffn.lin1.bias True
transformer.layer.3.ffn.lin2.weight True
transformer.layer.3.ffn.lin2.bias True
transformer.layer.3.output_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.3.output_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.4.attention.q_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.4.attention.q_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.4.attention.k_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.4.attention.k_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.4.attention.v_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.4.attention.v_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.4.attention.out_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.4.attention.out_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.4.sa_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.4.sa_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.4.ffn.lin1.weight True
transformer.layer.4.ffn.lin1.bias True
transformer.layer.4.ffn.lin2.weight True
transformer.layer.4.ffn.lin2.bias True
transformer.layer.4.output_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.4.output_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.5.attention.q_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.5.attention.q_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.5.attention.k_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.5.attention.k_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.5.attention.v_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.5.attention.v_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.5.attention.out_lin.weight True
transformer.layer.5.attention.out_lin.bias True
transformer.layer.5.sa_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.5.sa_layer_norm.bias True
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin1.weight True
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin1.bias True
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin2.weight True
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin2.bias True
transformer.layer.5.output_layer_norm.weight True
transformer.layer.5.output_layer_norm.bias True
...
```

Then if you have some list of layers you want to freeze, e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoModel

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

# Prefix of layer names to freeze.
tofreeze= set(["transformer.layer.4", "transformer.layer.5"])


for m in model.modules():
  for name, params in m.named_parameters():
    if any(prefix for prefix in tofreeze if name.startswith(prefix)):
        params.requires_grad = False
    print(name, params.requires_grad)
```

Comment: Hi @alvas, thank you so much for responding! I tried the approach you provided, but I got "AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'size'" when running this line 'bert_text = auto_model(text_input)' where auto_mode is the model initialized using AutoModel and text_input is tf.keras.Input. I read about it and one solution is to transform the kerastensor to torch tensor, but I am building the model using Tensorflow. Is there other solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to stick to tensorflow?

Comment: So the whole script is written in tensorflow, including tokenization and hyperparameter tuning using optuna. I am trying to experiment with small changes to the model architecture to see if that improves performance. If I'd switch to pytorch, would that be a lot of changes?

Comment: Without much knowledge of what your whole script/code does? It's hard to gauge what is the best path forward. If it's possible, please post a link or the code you're trying to use so that it can help us help you better.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I cannot provide the script, but I think your answer gave me a good understanding and I think the next best step might be switching to pytorch. Thanks a lot!